# How to check if Flash Player version is still supported and has recent updates?

Tags: windows, flash, flash-player, version, patch

We have to check the flash versions on some pcs. What we have are the version numbers of the installed software.

Is there any way to check if the versions are patched and currently supported?

What we found is this page: 
https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

It seems to have all versions but without the information about the life cycle.

**Edit**
From the list above: Adobe seems to patch older version also:

```
(Released 6/9/2015)  Flash Player 11.2.202.466 (32.43 MB)
(Released 6/9/2015)  Flash Player 13.0.0.292 (172.62 MB)
```

Comment: @Ramhound I edited the post

Comment: Given that each release is fixing security issues you should just install the latest version on all PCs. See https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_18_air_18_release_notes.html#id_62973 for the security enhancements for each version.

Comment: @boboes - It seems clear to me.  `Flash Player 11.2.202.466` ( Linux ).  Since you are using WIndows the current version is 17.x with 18.x being in Beta.

Comment: Flash Player 13 is extended release.  It means its basically Flash Player 11 but will be supported for a significant amount of time and the features will be stable.  Its the replacement for FP 11 Enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following process:

- Look up an old version using a site specific search query, such as:

  ```
  "flash player 9" site:adobe.com
  ```

It provides the following guidance:

> Adobe’s stated support policy for Adobe Flash Player is to support the current and previous major release

- Use the subdomain in another search to find the release notes:

  ```
  "release notes" site:helpx.adobe.com
  ```

As per the stated support policy, Flash Player 18 and Flash Player 17 are currently supported.

**References**

- [Researching with Search Engine Operators](http://www.bruceclay.com/newsletter/1004/seoperators.html)
- [Flash Player 9 Support Discontinued](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-9-support-discontinued.html)
- [Flash Player Help / Release Notes](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/flash-player-releasenotes.html)
- [Adobe: Discontinued or Unsupported products](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/policy-pricing/discontinued-products.html)
- [Adobe products and Enterprise Technical Support
  periods covered under the new Lifecycle Policy](http://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/eol/eol_matrix.html)
- [Exploring full-screen mode in Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html)

Answer (score -1):

Adobe patches older versions only for Linux, in which current versions have been available only for the Chrome Pepper API for some time.  Otherwise, you should generally run the latest version available for your OS.  You can easily check your installed version and learn the current version by going to http://www.flashtester.org and following the test link at the top.  The maintainer for that page also provides information on updates and security issues.